# Fibonacci using a recursive method gives me stack overflow

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, fibonacci

```
public static int rFib(int n) {

    if(n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    if(n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }  

    return n + rFib(n-1);
}
```

I am trying to find the largest number that will compute in under 60 seconds. Then I will use an iterative method to compare. Any number greater than 10,000 gives a stack-overflow error. How do I avoid this?

Comment: Try to store some results in an array fib[i] to reduce the cost of unnecessary method calls maybe?

Comment: *"How do I avoid this?"* Don't use recursion. --- You *could* increase the stack size, but that would just raise the limit. Fibonacci can be calculated without using recursion.

Comment: `10,000 gives a stack-overflow error.` - what would expect?

Comment: @buræquete That would improve performance, but would not fix stack-overflow error. With number greater than 10,000, the result is a call stack 10,000 deep, and of course that leads to stack-overflow error.

Comment: @Andreas But there would be many method call skips if the array contains the value, the depth would not be 10,000 deep, would it?

Comment: you can increase the stack size by passing a JVM argument : -Xss1024k

Comment: *FYI:* Your implementation is wrong. You implemented `f(n) = n + f(n-1)`, but Fibonacci function is `f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)`

Comment: You should use tail recursion

Comment: @buræquete The method in the question is recursing `rFib(n-1)`. There is no skipping going on.

Comment: @JRowan Java is not guaranteed to JIT compile tail recursion into loop, so tail recursion may still cause stack overflow.

Comment: @buræquete And even with correct formula, and use of memoization, you'd only get stack depth improvement if you changed from `f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)` to `f(n) = f(n-2) + f(n-1)`, and then you'd still just double the supported limit before stack overflow occurs. Non-recursive implementation can support unlimited range (without numeric overflow if you change to use `BigInteger`).

Comment: 10,000 also gives an integer overflow error. It would also take several years to compute even if it didn't overflow anything. It is a completely pointless test value. The maximum practical `int` input value is about 50, and it will surprise you how long it takes to compute with a correct recursive implementation and no memoization.

Answer (score 4):

One solution to this recursion problem is to break the recursion using dynamic programming. For example, [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) can be applied and allow you to implement it like

```
private static Map<Integer, Integer> memo = new HashMap<>();
static {
    memo.put(0, 0);
    memo.put(1, 1);
}

public static int rFib(int n) {
    if (memo.containsKey(n)) {
        return memo.get(n);
    }
    int r = rFib(n - 2) + rFib(n - 1);
    memo.put(n, r);
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately, you have come across the problem which is both the single most-used example for understanding recursion and almost the single worst application to apply recursion to.**

It's really simple to understand recursion from the fibonacci because it's a really trivial recursive algorithm for you to explain to somebody and understand... Which means it's great for programming recursion, right? Unfortunately, no.

I apologize if I'm going to tell you things you already know, but I know that fibonacci is one of the first examples in introductory programming so I'm assuming that's where you're coming from.

There's a thing in programming called a stack. It's literally called this because it's like a stack of papers. When you call a function, it puts onto the stack all the information needed to call the function, pass the arguments, and know how to return from the function (and some other administrative stuff). When that function recursively calls itself, *it puts another sheet on top of the stack*. Then that function puts **another** sheet. These sheets aren't removed until the function finishes... But since one function can't finish before the other one finishes, it just grows and grows and grows.

And the stack is only so big. Purposely. To avoid this problem.

Normally, recursion isn't used for such deep problems. *(Tail-call-recursive people: ignore this; if you don't know what tail-call-recusion is: also ignore this.)*

The way to fix this is to not do it. It's generally recognized that in nearly every arbitrarily-recursive function application, a `for` loop will work better (and faster).

Comment: No apologies needed, I am a student and still learning. I agree and would not use recursion for this problem, but it was instructed to do so. I am taking an algorithm design class and this was assigned to show how recursion is not always the best. We are just learning about dynamic programming so I will try to take that approach. Thank you for the input!